# Come posso dire con stile "Non ‘fate del male’ agli altri perché il karma ve la farà pagare cara"? Traduzione di ‘no escupas para arriba’

Tags: translation, idioms, figures-of-speech

Gli ispanoparlanti abbiamo l'espressione ‘**¡no escupas para arriba!**’ (letteralmente ‘non sputare verso l'alto!’). Questa espressione è usata per avvertire colui che causa il male (nel senso più ampio del termine) che il destino le castigherà. Ho trovato [questa descrizione](https://www.eldia.es/cultura/2021/07/03/escupas-caer-54619109.html) che ritengo molto accurata (traduzione mia).

> È un'espressione universale, come dimostra la sua presenza in altre lingue [anche italiano?], che funziona come una massima d'ammonizione. In questo senso, può essere usata in diverse situazioni. Le più frequenti suggeriscono e mettono in guardia chi si prende gioco o si rallegra delle avversità altrui; oppure chi proclama incautamente opinioni, giudica e critica gli altri per i loro disgrazie. In questo modo, siamo invitati alla prudenza e a non parlare troppo, perché la sfortuna può colpire chi è spietato con gli altri, che potrebbero essere trascinati in una situazione simile. Perché, come dice altro vecchio proverbio, ‘la vita prende molte pieghe’ e "non si potrà mai dire: ‘da quest'acqua non berrò’".
>
> [...]Ciò che è disprezzato, cioè ciò che non ha valore ed è ripudiato (lo sputo), viene gettato verso chi è il oggeto dell'oltraggio, pur non sapendo che può cadere sulla testa di chi sputa. E questa interpretazione appare su un substrato subliminale nell'atteggiamento di chi critica, parla male di qualcuno, lo deride o lo denigra in qualsiasi modo.
>
> [...]Un'espressione vicina a questa è quella che dice: ‘Raccogli ciò che semini’ [...]; anche questa frase può avere un significato ambivalente [buono o cattivo].
>
> [...]In definitiva, **il significato più profondo del detto ‘non sputare verso l'alto perché potrebbe ricadere su di te’ [...] è legato a una specie di principio retributivo universale che si esprime nel fatto che ogni male che causiamo, prima o poi, possono essere rivoltati contro di noi**.

**L'autore afferma che l'espressione è universale, posso dire ‘non sputare verso l'alto’ anche in italiano? Che espressioni idiomatique usate in queste situazioni?**

**APPENDICE** Tre essempi affinché capiscano la versatilità ed il senso dell'espressione

> A: —non trovi divertente che X sia stato cacciato da scuola? Scommetto che suo padre lo picchierà con il nastro.
> B: —*¡No escupas para arriba!* (lo stesso potrebbe accadere a te)

> A: —Non posso farte questo favore, lo sai bene che non faccio favori a quelli come tu [ad esempio, di un certo gruppo etnico].
> B: —*¡No escupas para arriba!* (un giorno mi chiederai un favore)

> A: —Odio l* ragazz* di X, ... [insulti, *sacada de cuero*] ...
> B: —*¡No escupas para arriba!* (chi ci dice che domani non sarà l* tu* ragazz*?)

Comment: Credo di aver sentito qualcosa sul fatto di sputare contro vento, ma non saprei dire da chi o dove, e neppure se il significato sia lo stesso.

Comment: Personalmente, non avevo mai sentito "no escupas para arriba" in spagnolo. Dalle mie parti, non credo si usi questa espressione.

Comment: @DaG "pisciare" contro vento.

Answer (score 5):

Non conosco nessun'espressione italiana che abbia il significato e la versatilità dell'espressione spagnola. In particolare non avevo mai sentito dire "non sputare verso l'alto", anche se si tratta di un'espressione di facile comprensione. Di sicuro avrei bisogno di rifletterci un attimo se qualcuno la usasse con me.

La frase più vicina che mi viene in mente è "si raccoglie quel che si semina" o persino "chi semina vento raccoglie tempesta", anche se la seconda l'ho sempre associata più al seminar zizzania che ad azioni generiche.

Tieni conto che questi detti in Italia spesso sono di carattere regionale, una frase comune a Napoli potrebbe causare confusione a Palermo o a Milano...

Answer (score 3):

In italiano, esiste il proverbio "Chi la fa, l'aspetti", associato al fatto che chi agisce male prima o poi, in un modo o nell'altro, ne pagherà le conseguenze ricevendo a sua volta qualcosa di simile da qualcun altro, ma non propriamente associata al karma.

Answer (score 1):

Io direi: La ruota gira, il karma non perdona. 
Aggiornamento 
Su Internet ho trovato questo pseudo proverbio cinese (io sono cinese) che potrebbe combaciare la tua idea: Boomerang e cattiverie tornano sempre indietro.

Comment: Tu lo diresti, ma è un modo di dire attestato?

Comment: Mi sembra che abbia chiesto come dirlo con stile, non necessariamente un corrispondente proverbio o una frase idiomatica.

Comment: Veramente, dice letteralmente (ortografia a parte): “Che espressioni idiomatique usate in queste situazioni?”

Comment: Scusate, non ho avuto la pazienza di leggere tutto quello che ha scritto. No, la frase che direi non è idiomatica, però può essere una valida risposta al titolo della sua domanda, intanto la frase idiomatica che cerca a quanto pare non c'è.

Comment: Bene, grazie per il chiarimento.

Comment: @DaG A questo punto mi dà lo stesso. Se è una frase che ha stile e che *può essere* pronunciata in una conversazione va bene

Comment: @DaG Grazie per aver puntualizzato il problema.

Answer (score 1):

Sebbene occorra fare ricerche in merito all'attestazione dei seguenti proverbi, si potrebbe citare primariamente la traduzione italiana –letteraria– di «Non sputare in cielo che in faccia ti ritorna».
Un proverbio alternativo sarebbe «La ruota gira, per tutti», volendo intendere che la ruota, essendo un cerchio, gira all'infinito non avendo un punto d'inizio e di fine come un segmento, pertanto nel momento più inatteso riceverai ciò che hai dato (se hai fatto del male ti tornerà indietro).
Un altro proverbio, attribuito alla tradizione cinese, è «Siediti sulla riva del fiume e aspetta che il cadavere del tuo nemico passi galleggiando», volendo far sottintendere d'avere pazienza nell'attesa di quel che avverrà.

Comment: Immagino che tu intenda traduzione “letterale”.

Comment: Si dice anche in italiano fuori Napoli? In napoletano è un'espressione piuttosto diffusa: "Nun sputà ncielo, ca nfaccia te torna".

Comment: "La ruota gira, per tutti" è generico, può voler anche dire che se fai bene, avrai del bene. E secondo me il proverbio "cinese" non c'entra un tubo.